# C token loop segfault issue

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, valgrind

So sort of new to C and I am trying to make a listener so that User has to press enter twice to completed typing there input. Then split by the new line and run all the data through a loop and send them through my functions.

I am not sure what i am doing wrong but when the loop right under "`//segfaulting` at loop" in the code is commented out it runs fine but when I uncomment it and have my call to "`//   assemble(ftemp);`" commented it out it is segfaulting so i know it here just dont know what. Valgrind says the below if that helps at all.

Thanks In Advanced Pete.

```
==14639== Invalid read of size 1

==14639==    at 0x4E7754C: ____strtod_l_internal (strtod_l.c:608)

==14639==    by 0x4011F8: main (in /home)

==14639==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

==14639== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

==14639==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0

==14639==    at 0x4E7754C: ____strtod_l_internal (strtod_l.c:608)

==14639==    by 0x4011F8: main (in /home)

==14639==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack

==14639==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but

==14639==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the

==14639==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.

==14639==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.

==14639== HEAP SUMMARY:

==14639==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==14639==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated

==14639== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible

==14639== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v

==14639== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

My code:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

printf("Please Enter In Float (Hit Enter Twice To Exicute)\n" );
#define MAXLENGTH 1000
char Input_string[MAXLENGTH];
int ilop = 0;
for(;;++ilop)
{
    Input_string[ilop] = getchar();
    if (ilop > 0 && Input_string[ilop] == '\n' &&
 Input_string[ilop-1] == '\n') break;
}
Input_string[ilop] = 0;

 char *pch;
//  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",Input_string);
pch = strtok (Input_string,"\n");
float ftemp = atof(pch);
//printf("price:, %f\n\n",ftemp);

assemble(ftemp);
 //segfaulting at loop
while (pch != NULL)
{
 pch = strtok (NULL, "\n");
 ftemp = atof(pch);
   printf("price:, %f\n\n",ftemp);
//   assemble(ftemp);
 }


 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You don't check the `pch` inside the loop. So it can be (and eventually will be) NULL.

Comment: First step in bugfixing would be formatting your code, so you can actually read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on what Igal S. said, you’re first setting `strtok` inside the loop, then using it, and not checking it until the top of the loop.  So, on the last iteration, it will set `pch` to `NULL`, then pass it to `atof()` without checking it.

You need something like (untested):

```
pch = strtok (Input_string, "\n");
while (pch != NULL)
{
  /* ... */
  pch = strtok (NULL, "\n");
}
```

Comment: The first call should be `pch = strtok (Input_string,"\n");`

Answer (score 2):

There is a possibility of array out of bound access which might lead to undefined behavior.

In the for loop at the beginning add the check

```
if(ilop > 999)
{
   break;
}
```

Comment: Or construct the `for` loop properly.